# Implementing Queue using Linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to implement queue using linked lists. Here is my program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queue_struct{
    int ele;
    struct queue_struct *next;
};

struct Queue{
    struct queue_struct *front, *rear;
};

int isEmpty(struct Queue *q){
    return (q->front==NULL||q->rear==NULL);
}

void enqueue(struct Queue *q, int x){
    struct queue_struct *temp=(struct queue_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue_struct));
    temp->ele=x;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(isEmpty(q)){
        q->front=q->rear=temp;
        return;
    }
    q->rear=temp;
    printf("The item %d has been enqueued into the queue\n", x);
}

void dequeue(struct Queue *q){
    if(isEmpty(q)){
        printf("The queue is already empty. No more elements can be removed!\n");
        return;
    }
    struct queue_struct *temp=q->front;
    printf("The item %d has been dequeued from the queue\n", temp->ele);
    q->front=q->front->next;
    if(q->front=NULL)
        q->rear=NULL;
    free(temp);
}

void display(struct Queue *q){
    struct queue_struct *temp=q->front;
    int len;
    printf("The contents of the queue are:\n");
    if(isEmpty(q)){
        printf("Nothing to be shown, the queue is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
        len++;
    }
    temp=q->front;
    for(int i=1;i<len-1;i++){
        printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
        printf(" ------ \n");
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
}

int main()
{
    int choice, element;
    printf("LET'S START WITH AN EMPTY QUEUE\n\n");
    struct Queue *q=(struct Queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    q->front=q->rear=NULL;
    while(1){
        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("----\n");
        printf("\t1. Enqueue\n");
        printf("\t2. Dequeue\n");
        printf("\t3. Display queue\n");
        printf("\t4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: printf("Enter the element to be enqueued: ");
                    scanf("%d", &element);
                    enqueue(q, element);
                    break;
            case 2: dequeue(q);
                    break;
            case 3: display(q);
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Program terminated successfully!\n");
                    return 0;
            default: printf("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I'm trying to enqueue an element, I'm getting a segmentation fault

Upon debugging I find that my isEmpty() function is the culprit, but I can't seem to find the problem. Considering the nature of the problem, I thought the front OR rear should be NULL for the queue to be empty. Am I wrong in my understanding? Any help is appreciated.

*Edit*
As suggested by @interjay, I have made changes to the `q=NULL` part of the `main()` method. However, my `display` method is now going awry. I don't understand why.

Comment: For some reason you have `q=NULL;` immediately after allocating `q`.

Comment: @interjay that's so that I can start with an empty queue

Comment: `q==NULL` is not the same as `q->front==NULL || q->rear==NULL`. You need to decide which of those means "empty queue".

Comment: @interjay thank you for the insight. However, the code is now giving me a segmentation fault for the display() method. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues.

In `main`, doing `q = NULL;` is a memory leak and will produce a segfault. The correct way to initialize an empty queue is:

```
q->front = NULL;
q->rear = NULL;
```

The queue display uses a `while` loop to find the end of the queue, thus guaranteeing that `temp` will be `NULL` in the subsequent `for` loop (i.e. segfault). Only the `for` loop is needed

`enqueue` does *not* properly handle appending to a non-empty list.

`dequeue` has an if statement that uses the assignment operator `if (q->front = NULL)` instead of the equality operator `if (q->front == NULL)`. But, even with that fix, it still doesn't handle the operation correctly.

There really isn't much use for `isEmpty` function with the other functions as they can/should just check `front`.

Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Doing the cast can introduce subtle, hard to find bugs.

---

Here's a refactored version that fixes the issues. I did a bit of cleanup/renaming of some of the `struct` names to be a bit more descriptive of function.

In the code below, I used `cpp` conditionals to show the changes (e.g.):

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

I've annotated the bugs where possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queue_element QElement;
struct queue_element {
    int ele;
    QElement *next;
};

typedef struct Queue {
    QElement *front, *rear;
} Queue;

int
isEmpty(Queue *q)
{
    return (q->front == NULL || q->rear == NULL);
}

void
enqueue(Queue *q, int x)
{
    QElement *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    temp->ele = x;
    temp->next = NULL;

// NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ append correctly to a non-empty list
#if 0
    if (isEmpty(q)) {
        q->front = q->rear = temp;
        return;
    }

    q->rear = temp;
#else
    // link old rear node to new node
    if (q->rear != NULL)
        q->rear->next = temp;

    // set new rear node
    q->rear = temp;

    // set the front of the list if it was empty
    if (q->front == NULL)
        q->front = temp;
#endif

    printf("The item %d has been enqueued into the queue\n", x);
}

void
dequeue(Queue *q)
{
    QElement *temp = q->front;

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("The queue is already empty. No more elements can be removed!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("The item %d has been dequeued from the queue\n", temp->ele);

    q->front = temp->next;
    if (q->rear == temp)
        q->rear = NULL;

    free(temp);
}

void
dequeue_OLD(Queue *q)
{
    if (isEmpty(q)) {
        printf("The queue is already empty. No more elements can be removed!\n");
        return;
    }
    QElement *temp = q->front;

    printf("The item %d has been dequeued from the queue\n", temp->ele);
    q->front = q->front->next;
// NOTE/BUG: this if is invalid -- it is using the assignment operator in
// place of the [desired] equality operator
// NOTE/BUG: even with this fix, the dequeue is still broken -- see the fix
// above
#if 0
    if (q->front = NULL)
        q->rear = NULL;
#else
    if (q->front == NULL)
        q->rear = NULL;
#endif
    free(temp);
}

void
display(Queue *q)
{
    QElement *temp = q->front;

    printf("The contents of the queue are:\n");

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Nothing to be shown, the queue is empty.\n");
        return;
    }

// NOTE/BUG: doing the while loop ensures that temp will be NULL so that the
// for loop will try to dereference temp and it will segfault
#if 0
    int len;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        len++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++) {
        printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
        printf(" ------ \n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
#else
    int sep = 0;
    for (;  temp != NULL;  temp = temp->next) {
        if (sep)
            printf(" ------ \n");
        sep = 1;
        printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
    }
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{
    int choice, element;

    printf("LET'S START WITH AN EMPTY QUEUE\n\n");
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
// NOTE/BUG: setting q to NULL ensures a segfault and is a memory leak
#if 0
    q = NULL;
#else
    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
#endif

    while (1) {
        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("----\n");
        printf("\t1. Enqueue\n");
        printf("\t2. Dequeue\n");
        printf("\t3. Display queue\n");
        printf("\t4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the element to be enqueued: ");
            scanf("%d", &element);
            enqueue(q, element);
            break;
        case 2:
            dequeue(q);
            break;
        case 3:
            display(q);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Program terminated successfully!\n");
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I noticed that when I run this code. It throws an error for the line ```QElement *temp = malloc(*temp);``` saying ```error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘malloc’```. Why is that?

Comment: My bad. I did that edit as a final cleanup before posting, but I didn't recompile [as I normally do]. I've edited the answer and added the fix: `QElement *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));`

Answer (score 0):

There are the following issues:

- You should not assign `NULL` to `q`, since that is the pointer to the memory you had just allocated, and which holds the pointers `front` and `rear`, which you will need *always*, even when the queue is empty. Instead you should set those `front` and `rear` pointers to  `NULL`:

  ```
  q->front = q->rear = NULL;
  ```
- In `dequeue` you have an *assignment* inside an `if` condition, where you actually want a *comparison*. Change this:

  ```
  if(q->front=NULL)
  ```

  to:

  ```
  if(q->front==NULL)
  ```
- In `display` you are dereferencing `temp` after the first loop, where you are sure that it is actually `NULL`. So this is going to raise an exception. You should only have *one* loop. Any attempt to loop again over the list with the same `temp` pointer would need the `temp` pointer to be reset to the `front`. Here is a simple replacement for your `display` function:

  ```
  void display(struct Queue *q){
      struct queue_struct *temp=q->front;
      printf("The contents of the queue are:\n");
      if(isEmpty(q)){
          printf("Nothing to be shown, the queue is empty.\n");
          return;
      }
      while(temp!=NULL){
          printf("%d->", temp->ele);
          temp=temp->next;
      }
      printf("NULL\n");
  }
  ```

  if you want an `i` counter to be displayed as well, then just increment it in the *same* loop above.

With these changes your code will work.